# "WebSocket is closed before the connection is established"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

When I click the button `startChat` then the `websocket` connection is established and once when I click `hideChat` the `websocket` connection should be disconnected.

```
const startChat = () => { 
    let webSocketConnection = "wss://ulw5fo03rf.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev"
    var socket = new WebSocket(webSocketConnection)
    setShowChat(true);
    socket.onopen = function(event){ console.log('Connection Established'); }
  }

const hideChat = () => {
    let webSocketConnection = "wss://ulw5fo03rf.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev"
    var socket = new WebSocket(webSocketConnection)
    socket.close()
    setShowChat(false);
    console.log('Socket closed') 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are two separate socket instances even if they're running on the same endpoint, you need to make it a shared variable between the two functions and reference it accordingly